# Automorphisms of graphs - vertex and edge transitive

Tags: graph-theory

I want to find a simple graph that is vertex but not edge transitive. Am I right in thinking a path for example $P_3$ would be one? But then the middle vertex is just mapped to itself? 
I can find large examples online but it's not really helping my understanding.  Any help appreciated

Comment: $P_3$ is not vertex transitive. Vertex transitive means you can map any vertex to any other vertex with an automorphism.

Comment: Thanks. So a complete graph would be vertex transitive,  but also edge transitive? Have you any examples that is vertex but not edge transitive.  A simple enough one?

Comment: I don't have any examples. I'm not a student of graph theory. You are correct that a complete graph is both vertex and edge transitive, as is a cycle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the prism on a $n$-cycle ($C_n\square K_2$). Imagine it with one cycle on the bottom plane, one on the top plane and vertical edges completing the prism.

You can easily see that rotating makes all corners in the top plane equivalent (even as a solid), and turning the prism upside down makes them equivalent to the corners in the bottom plane.

When $n=3$ it is particular easy to show that the "horizontal" and the "vertical" edges are not equivalent. Do so! Remember that you must show non-equivalence in the graph, not in the solid.

It may be instructive to figure out which values of $n$ do *not* provide an example, and to prove that all other values of $n$ *do* provide an example (it is not hard).